NestJs Cron Jobs Which Previously Worked Are not Functioning
We're using NestJS scheduler for cron jobs, we've had a certain amount of cron tasks which have been running without any issues in production. However we've recently doubled the amount of cron tasks, and the old crons are no longer working. The new tasks run every second to 5 seconds and the old crons run every 30 mins to 6 hours. If I remove the new crons, the old ones begin working again. We use AWS Elasticache and redis, I'm not very familiar with it; it looks like we aren't maxing out our cache but I'm not sure. Before I scale up I want to make sure it's not some sort of concurrency issue with Nestjs itself. Any Ideas?

enter image description here
